# Permit access to website with load balancer (changing IP), disable rest with iptables

Tags: iptables, load-balancing

I need to block access to all websites except for a couple of URLs on a group of workstations. Apparently a few of these websites are load balanced. I use iptables:

```
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s my.dns.ip -j ACCEPT # local DNS

... # some other websites
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s www.rcsb.org -j ACCEPT # problematic website, load balanced?

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -j REJECT
```

Soon I'm going to test if this will help:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED
```

But maybe you guys know better how to allow incoming (responses) traffic from a pool of web servers (IPs) behind load balancer?

Comment: Conntrack (your second example) will definitely help but may not be enough, as your ACCEPT rule will resolve the hostname when loaded and only take its first IP; if a client wants to later access the site and gets a different IP (because of DNS-based load balancing) your firewall will block the connection. A possible solution would be to provide a proxy that applies ACLs to hostnames (and eventually URLs) regardless of IPs, and your users will need to use that to access the net (direct HTTP traffic should be blocked). Plus, you'll have better logging of all URLs accessed.

Comment: This will depend on how the websites are set up with regards to both DNS and the type of load balancing. Do you have any information about this that you could add to your question? (Also, I agree with @AndréDaniel that it would probably be far easier to set up a proxyserver.)

Comment: The webservice in question is load balanced based on location. I don't know the details, I think that all requests from Europe are served from one location in the East Coast of US. I'll try with the solution using proxy, thanks guys.

Answer (score -1):

oops i misread the question....  this may be closer to what your looking for? filter on outbound traffic?

> iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
>
> iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
>
> for x in $(cat list.of.allowed.websites.txt); do for i in $(dig $x +short | cut -d\  -f[theip]); do iptables -A OUTPUT -d $i/32 -j ACCEPT; done; done
>
> allow all the usual outgoing... ntp, dchp, DNS,etc...

EDIT: above would be iptables ruleset on your enduser hosts on private lan that need to be restricted (so input accept policy not terrible). it may be better to not have hostbased ruleset tho, but just have one set on default gateway router with FORWARD instead of OUTPUT

if any of the website's dns names resolve to more than one ip, the bash oneliner would need to be smarter. many loadbalancers only use one external ip for incoming traffic.  i think amazon elb does one per az its registered in.

(accept input default policy is not great, may be better solution)

Comment: I think you misread the question. It's not about how to differentiate incoming traffic to different questions - it's about how to allow clients to send and receive return traffic only to/from certain websites, which may be behind load balancers.

Comment: Exactly @JennyD , I don't know all IP addresses from a pool behind the load balancer and I also don't know the size of this pool. Also I know that iptables doesn't work with domains, they're resolved. I hoped that I could somehow solve it with the current software stack, but it seems that the proxy, as suggested by andré-daniel is the way to go.

Comment: @januszm With some load balancers, all traffic basically gets NAT'ed so that only the load balancer's IP address is visible to your clients. With others, you may get return traffic coming from the server's other IP. Also, some sites may be resolve to more than one IP, and I'm not sure how IPTables handles that.